# Need to compare values of two columns in one table

Tags: crystal-reports

[image]

I want to compare values of column A with all the values of column B and remove all duplicate values from both columns.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Iti for editing my requirement, it is much more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Create a sub report and place in report header

In sub report place tableB column in detail section and store all values in shared array variable.

Create a formula and write below code and place it in detail section after the database field

```
    Shared Stringvar arrray store;
    store:=store+databasefield;
    1  //This is the change
```

Make sure the decrease the width of sub report to lowest pixel and don't forget to place it in report header

Now go to main report and place table A field in detail section

Go to supress of the detail section and write the below code

```
Shared Stringvar arrray store;
if tableA.databasefield in store
Then true
else false
```

Comment: @Rumi you didn't follow the full process, I told you to supress aswell, and decrease the size of the formula as less as possible

Comment: Do I have to supress on the formula or on the tableB column?

Comment: @Rumi on the section where you display the data, post the design screenshot

Comment: I've just added few screenshots,  thanks for your time

Comment: Looks like you have messed up whole report, is your sub report completed successfully? and don't create any new formulas in sub report

Comment: I got a bit confused! Yes i created a formula in sub report. Added the first screenshot

Comment: The formula in sub report and works but when i come to the main report and try to add the formula in supress column A then stops working

Comment: Not on column instead on section where column A is placed

Comment: When i try to suppress it in detail section i get this error message " a variable cannot be redeclared with a different type"

Comment: @Rumi both declerations are `Shared StringVar Array` correct?

Comment: Yes correct  Formula in Sub_Report : Shared Stringvar array store;
store:= store+ {baseevent1.CROSS_REF};
1

Comment: @Rumi did you place the created formula on design in sub report?

Comment: Yes i added in the Details section after to the column B

Comment: posted the screenshot

Comment: Normally this error wont come close and open the report and chech

Comment: You're right by closing and opening the report the error is gone. I placed the sub_report in to the main report and i get the above screenshot output. Am i missing something?

Comment: Supress the sub report

Comment: it works but the report sill the same i mean didn't effect the report shows as before

Comment: can you add screenshot what you are getting?

Comment: Sure I've uploaded

Comment: @Rumi ok don't supress sub report instead supress the section where sub report is placed

Comment: Ok the go to sub report and supress the fields on design

Comment: I've done it and when i try to refresh the report formula window pops up   and i get the error: " An array's dimention must be an integer between 1 and 1000." and then blank page

Comment: Supress all fields in sub report not one

Comment: This looks like simple requirement but not sure where it is going wrong

Comment: You right.. let me take one step back it may be I'm doing something wrong. This what i get from the sub _report valuse of column B and Formula is this correct? See screenshot

Comment: Ok one last suggestion, If you have database access then write a custom query and implement the logic their and use that query in report. this will work for sure

Comment: Yeah you're right this will work and I thought about this but i can only read and retrieve from database

Comment: @Rumi read and retrive rights are sufficient for this requriement

Comment: Have you ever faced with this kind of problem or do you think is there any alternative way to solve this issue?

Comment: @Rumi Already gave you the alternate solution write custom query

Comment: Okay i will try and see how it goes